In 7 days to die, can locked treasure chests or quest chests be opened with explosives without destroying them?
When you get a treasure map and find the chest, it has 5000 HP. A dynamite says it does 3000 damage, so I thought it would help open the chest faster. But when I tried it, the chest blew up completely and the treasure quest failed.
Is it possible to do this right? How can the chest be destroyed when it has much more HP than the dynamite should deal damage?
Do other locked chests break open from dynamite or any other explosives?

IT is very likely you blew up all the dirt that was 'supporting' the treasure chest as the dirt blocks don't have much health and dynamite has a fairly large blast radius. Once that happens to any container it falls downwards until it hits another block, becoming an appropriate rubble block once it lands.
When trying to use explosives to open containers you'll want to stick to using timed explosives as the limited blast radius will make destroying the supporting blocks much less likely.
You've also got the option of using lockpicks, and lacking those you can bring lots of rocks, wood, and plant fiber to hack away at it with stone axes until it breaks!

I think this is correct. I tried again with an identical chest found in a house, and this time it worked. The dynamite took away about 3000 dmg from the chest and blew up some walls, but the chest remained and I could hack away the last HP to open it.
